# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options using @angular/fire": "^7.2.0

Tags: angular, angularfire2

i got this error -"NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!"

my libs version:

> angular version 13
> "firebase": "^9.4.0",
> "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",

my app.module

```
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFunctions,getFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    // FIRESTORE
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions(initializeApp(environment.firebase),'europe-west3')),
```

component

```
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
 @Component....

 constructor(private store:Store<personalDetailsState> 
    ,private fns: AngularFireFunctions
    ) { }
```